# Laravel 5 - Image Upload and Resize using Intervention Image Package

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I want to upload a photo with some posts.

This is my controller

```
public function store(WisataRequest $request)
{
  $input = $request->all();

  if ($request->hasFile('gambar')) {
    $gambar = $request->file('gambar');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $gambar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    if ($request->file('gambar')->isValid()) {
      Image::make($gambar)->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path('/upload/gambar/'.$filename));
      $input->gambar = $filename;
      $input->save();
    }
  }

  $wisata = Wisata::create($input);
  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Berhasil Terkirim');
  return redirect('admin_wisata');
}
```

But when it runs i found an error
**Attempt to assign property of non-object**

Comment: And this error is on which line?

Comment: what is WisataRequest?I think it should only be `Request`. Also declare it at the top : `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: @YaShChaudhary that is a user-defined Request built on top of Request. that's perfectly okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$input->gambar = $filename;
$input->save();
```

To

```
$input['gambar']= $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$input` variable is not an object, it is an array. You can try accessing gambar in `$input` by doing `$input['gambar']`

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
$input['gambar']= $filename;
```

Instead of

```
$input->gambar = $filename;
$input->save();
```

**OR**

```
public function store(WisataRequest $request)
{

  $wista = new Wista;
  $wist->name = $request->name;
  -----
  $wista->save();

  if ($request->hasFile('gambar')) {
    $gambar = $request->file('gambar');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $gambar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    if ($request->file('gambar')->isValid()) {
      Image::make($gambar)->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path('/upload/gambar/'.$filename));
      $wista->gambar = $filename;
      $wista->save();
    }


  }


  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Berhasil Terkirim');
  return redirect('admin_wisata');
}
```